# How to show $G/K$ acts on $A^K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ be an abelian group on which $G$ acts as automorphism, that 
is, $A$ is a $G$-module. Let $K$ be a normal subgoup of $G$. Let $A^K=\{a \in A:ka=a \mbox{ for all } k \in K\}$. I want to show that $G/K$ is acting on $A^K$.

I suppose that action is given as $(gK)a=ga$. Before showing that this is really an action I need to show that $ga \in A^K$ but I am not able to show this. I need to justify why $(ga)k=k$?

Comment: No, you cannot have $k$ on that side of the action. $k$ was an element of $K$, not of $A$. You need to check that if $a\in A^K$ then for all $g\in G$ and all $k\in K$ you have $k.(g.a) = g.a$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, Thanks for pointing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you must check:

a. the thing you noticed -- we need $ga \in A^K$

b. the action had better be well defined -- that is, if $gK = g'K$ then we must have $ga = g'a$.

For a, take $k \in K$. We must show $kga = ga$. This is equivalent to showing that $g^{-1}kga = a$. What can you say about $g^{-1}kg$? (what hypothesis haven't you used yet?)

For b,  if $gK = g'K$ then $g^{-1}g' \in K$, so...